# Is it possible to name the index within the loop, when creating a DataFrame using a loop?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is it possible to name the index values as you loop through some expression to  to create a DataFrame?

Here's my code, which works fine, but was wondering if it could be done differently. In this case the index is renamed after the loop (a for loop) has finished.

```
   #loop to produce regression df
   
   regression_stats_df = pd.DataFrame()

   for i in all_perf_time_series:
       regression_stats_df[i] = (beta, alpha, rsqr) = stats.linregress(all_perf_time_series['Benchmark'],all_perf_time_series[i])[0:3] 
   
   
   regression_stats_index = ['Beta', 'Alpha', 'Rsqr']

   regression_stats_df.index = regression_stats_index
```

Here's the output before I rename the index:
[image]

Here's the output after I rename the index:
[image]

So can I change/name the the index to 'Beta', 'Alpha', 'Rsqr' during the loop?

Comment: Why do you use a loop? You could just initialize `regression_stats_df = pd.DataFrame(index=['Beta', 'Alpha', 'Rsqr'])`

Comment: That's a great point. 
For me it was more if it were possible to do it in the loop itself. How would you go about it?

Comment: I just don't really see the point. Generating a DataFrame in a loop is usually not a good idea. Do you do something else in the loop? The canonical way would be to generate a list/dictionary with the loop, and only after to convert to DataFrame.

Comment: Ok, so with my code example you wouldn't populate regression_stats_df using the loop? How would you do it? I'm still on my learning journey.

Really I just wanted to see if you could name the index and create the values in the df at the same time. Rather than doing it one step after another.

Comment: I would use: `df = pd.DataFrame({col: stats.linregress(all_perf_time_series['Benchmark'],all_perf_time_series[i])[0:3] for col in all_perf_time_series}, index=['Beta', 'Alpha', 'Rsqr'])`

Comment: replacing i with col -> df = pd.DataFrame({col: stats.linregress(all_perf_time_series['Benchmark'],all_perf_time_series[col])[0:3] for col in all_perf_time_series}, index=['Beta', 'Alpha', 'Rsqr'])

Comment: Yes of course, sorry I missed that one ;)